# What is this design (or anti-) pattern and more importantly is there a better way?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm receiving from a webservice a list of key-value pairs, and have inherited the following code:

```
public String iconValue = null;
... (over 50 class variables assigned in MyObject constructor below)

public MyObject(List<Attribute> attrs) {

    String attrName, attrValue;

    for (Attribute a : attrs) {
        try
        {
            attrName = a.getName();
            attrValue = a.getValue();

            if (attrValue == null || "".equals(attrValue.trim()))
                continue;

            if (ICONS.equals(attrName)) {
                //Do something including assignment
                this.iconValue = attrValue;
            }
            else if (URL.equals(attrName)) 
            {
                //Do something including assignment
            }
            else if (...)  A giant list of over 50 different attributes hardcoded
            {
                //Do something including assignment
            }

            ...
```

So,except for keeping a hashmap - is there a better way than the above to keep hard coded variables within the class and use this "when-if" pattern.

Also,does this pattern have a name?

Comment: You could use reflections to get the setter method and set the values based on the attribute name, but since this looks/smells/feels like a Map, I'd really consider using a Map<String,String>.

Comment: @CodeChimp That's a cool idea..so essentially it would reduce all those lines to 2-3. Isn't reflection expensive though?

Comment: The code above reminds me of the Visitor pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: Not really a visitor, more of a command/strategy pattern, although I suppose it's a visitor in the sense it iterates over a collection. Whether or not it's worth actually *implementing* that pattern totally depends.

Comment: Reflections would most likely be a performance hit, but it would greatly shorten the amount of code needed, and would support easily adding new attributes as you would simply need to implement the appropriately matched setters.  It does have the downside of creating potential security problems (I think a Polish firm just found a vulnerability with Reflections in Java 7), and you would have to handle exceptions when the attribute being sent doesn't have a corresponding setter, but life is full of trade-offs, programming even more so. Why not just store the list of Attributes in a Map?

Comment: Another developer is quite fond of patterns and frameworks. My feeling is that in many cases this will hinder flexibility and also add overhead. Is it so bad to have spaghetti hardcoded stuff if it's faster... It's not that the code is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I can think about is to use `ENUM`s and dynamically dispatch the works to each of the `ENUM` object, instead of doing a huge if else, esp. since `ENUM`s can be looked up by their names.

That would be like a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

For example:

1. Implement an `ENUM` to have a method `doJob()` for each of the instances;
2. Use the [`valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) method to dispatch the works.

Code sample:

```
public enum Strategies {
    URL {
        @Override
        public void doJob(MyObject mo) {
                // do the work
        }
    },
    ICONS {
        @Override
        public void doJob(MyObject mo) {
                // another work
        }
    };
    public abstract void doJob(MyObject mo);
}
```

And when using it,

```
try {
    Strategies.valueOf(attrName).doJob();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // ENUM does not exist, illegal parameter
}
```

Comment: XMM...could you include an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a different action for each possible value of attribute, you will end up with something about that verbose, I'm afraid. Some improvements though:

If you are using Java7 or above, you can now use `switch` statements with Strings ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html))

If you are not, you could create an Enum that has a static method that returns an Enum element you could switch on. It's no performance improvement, but it might help with readability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this pattern have a name?

Nope.

In Java 7 you can express that as:

```
  switch (attrName) {
  case ICONS:
      //Do something including assignment
      break;
  case URL: 
      //Do something including assignment
      break;
  // and so on
  }
```

... provided that ICONS, URL and the other strings are compile-time constants.

That is more concise and more robust.  It is also (probably) more efficient because the switch can most likely be implemented using hashing.

Comment: Yes, they are compile time,specific public final static string so this would work. Seems to end up to a software beautification issue :(

Comment: @meewoK - I'm not so sure.  The performance implications of using a switch could be significant if there are enough switch cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has a name, but you could call it "using polymorphism wrong" (if type safety is a concern). It depends on whether you have a well defined data contract or not. Is the data you're receiving a proper object, or just "random" data?

If it's a proper object I would create a concrete representation and use something like Dozer (or if you don't want to be tied down wit dependency, roll your own mapper using reflection) to convert between them.

If it's more or less random data, I'd just use a Map, or similar data structure.